# What clear coat material would last as an exterior traffic surface?

Tags: outdoor, materials

I have an idea for a decorative project, but I haven't been able to find much information about which materials might work.

In short, think "thick bar top for a concrete walkway." Specifically, I'd like to be able to mix in phosphorescent powder, or pigments, and keep a transparent look to it.

It seems like most epoxies aren't designed to have other ingredients mixed in. I don't know how well polyurethane would hold up outdoors.

Any ideas for something durable and color-able?

Comment: Coatings and finishes like you are talking about are going to be smooth and could end up being rather dangerous to walk on in wet, icy or snow conditions. This would be especially true if your decorative project extends to an area equivalent to a walk way.

Comment: That's an important point to consider. My two thoughts on that were: It hasn't frozen in two years where I live ;-) And, it should be relatively easy to mitigate by texturing the surface as it sets... so long as the material tolerates that kind of manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

Many epoxies *are* designed to have other ingredients mixed in. That's basically West System's *hat*.  The garage floor epoxy paints all allow grit and chips to be mixed in too.

The problem is, **epoxy is quickly destroyed by UV light**, notably from the sun.

There are several other 2-part coatings, and *surfboard people* are the experts: they work with every kind.  TAP Plastics is a retailer in the west (yes, a retail store you can walk in and buy this stuff) and they have extensive literature about the ups and downs of each 2-part coating system.